# I need some clarification regarding document "structure/type" in Microsoft Form Recognizer docs

Tags: ocr, azure-cognitive-services

In [Form Recognizer documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/python-train-extract), it is said that " You should have a minimum of five filled-in forms (PDF documents and/or images) of the same type/structure as your main input data ". My data is mostly tabular, but some differ in number of columns and what is inside of them. For instance, some are [like this](https://i0.wp.com/c1.staticflickr.com/3/2599/32722255090_cb82a1a8b2_o.png?resize=574%2C736&ssl=1) -- but with numbers in the columns -- and others are similar to [this one](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Sabari_Nathan4/post/How_to_use_machine_learning_techniqueto_extract_the_tables_from_scanned_document_images/attachment/59d622766cda7b8083a1c8a1/AS%3A273796672491521%401442289621609/image/tes3.jpg).

My question is whether they can be considered as the same "type/structure" since they are all tabular or if they can't since they are somewhat different.

If they cannot be considered the same type, would it hurt most of the performance if I use them together as my training samples for "tabular documents" in general?

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but I'd really appreciate if someone could redirect me to somewhere I can ask this or answer my question :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as far as I'm concerned (I started using Form Recognizer last week), when it says the same type/structure, it means that all files must be the same extension (all PDFs or all JPEGs) and all of them must have the same columns/fields with the same names/headers on the same places so that the model can recognize these fields as keys and then extract the values associated with those keys.

So, in your case, I think you would have to train different models for the different structures of your files.

Hope it helps!